# replace a character that indicates a new line in NotePad++

Tags: notepad++

I have the text as follows in notepad++ editor.
`Sample Text in the~
File`
In the above text, when we encounter `~` symbol the information flows into next line. There are several occurrences of above in the text.
How do I remove the special char `~` and make it as a single line in notepad++

so, my final output is `Sample Text in theFile`

I know it can be done by regex of notepad++, but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Press `Ctrl + H`. When Replace pop-up is appeared, in `Search Mode` section select `Extended`. In the `Find what:` input type `~` and in the `Replace with` input type `\n`. At the end click on `Replace All` button.

Comment: This replaces `~` with a `\n` but don't achieve what I want. :(..

Comment: So replace `~\r\n` by empty(I mean nothing in `Replace with` section)

Answer (score 2):

In the replace screen (CTRL+H), check the Regular expression box. Fill the input boxes as follows:

Find what:

```
~\R
```

Replace with:

```
(leave blank)
```

Comment: Notepad++ Says  0 occurrences were replaced and no change in my file.

Comment: Try \n~ instead if your file uses that format for line endings.

Comment: Sorry, it should be ~\r\n

Comment: I just found it should be `~\n`. Your answer is very very close though. Thanks a lot for the help....

Comment: With searchmode Regular expression it is possible to use `\R` which matches either lineending, so the search becomes `~\R`.

Comment: That's a nice addition. Tested it on both Unix- and Windows line endings and it worked.